# Get a value from an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, json, object

How do I get the id `43` from `country` ?

```
"hq_locations":[{"id":1886112,"address":"10 Rue Laurencin, 69002 Lyon, France","street":"Rue Laurencin","street_number":"10","zip":"69002","lat":45.7527311,"lon":4.8321804,"country":{"id":43,"name":"France","lat":46.227638,"lon":2.213749,"trade_register_office":"Info Greffe"}
```

Comment: hq_locations[0].country.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is probably not working is because the hq_locations contains an array that contains an object that contains a child object and some properties.

As you can see the levels you have to bypass before you get to the id of the country is more than just selecting the object in the object and then its property.

An example to access the first element in the row:

```
const obj = {
    "hq_locations": [{
        "id": 1886112,
        "address": "10 Rue Laurencin, 69002 Lyon, France",
        "street": "Rue Laurencin",
        "street_number": "10",
        "zip": "69002",
        "lat": 45.7527311,
        "lon": 4.8321804,
        "country": {
            "id": 43,
            "name": "France",
            "lat": 46.227638,
            "lon": 2.213749,
            "trade_register_office": "Info Greffe"
        }
    }]
};

console.log(obj.hq_locations[0].country.id)
```

If you want to access all the elements in the array and select all the ids you'd have to loop it:

```
   for (let i = 0; i < obj.hq_locations.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj.hq_locations[i].id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is weird this is what i'm doing but I have a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" whereas he can read the value hq_locations[0].country and get me the properties. But when I want to access one of the properties I get this message above.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid maybe because of that.

Comment: Thank you for your help I did find the answer :)

Comment: Well done, maybe update your post for the next person with a similar issue.